# Перемещение объектов по картинке в iOS

Tags: xcode, ios

Здравствуйте!

Хочу сделать что-то типа монополии, когда есть ката и по ней перемещаются фишки. 
Мне нужно, чтобы в ходе игры объект перемещался по карте с помощью анимации. Это сделать не сложно, но как быть с разными разрешениями экрана? Как правильно задавать координаты перемещения (x, y), чтобы на различных размерах экранов объект перемещался в одно и то же место? Как быть с горизонтальной и вертикальной ориентацией?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пересчитывайте координаты для каждого разрешения.

Хотя есть подозрение, что вы используете обычный интерфейс для игры? Не проще всё сделать с помощью SpriteKit?

Comment: Да, совсем не подумал, спасибо за совет!